# SSRS - Show/Hide group-row based on page number

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to show/hide a group-header-row based on page number. No way I could access the page number inside the group to add an expression based on the page number. All I need is to show a group-header-row only from second page (hide the row in first page).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, SSRS 2016.

Everything works fine except hiding the Group Header 2 from Page 1.

Comment: Will the group header show more than once per page or can you simply hide it if its the first instance of the group header within the Tablix? If so you could compare the group value to the minimum group value from the dataset and if they match , you know if the first instance of the group. Just thinking out loud so this is untested but that's how I might approach it.

Comment: Thanks Alan for the quick reply.It is not a table structured report. It is a form based report which has details in each row of a table and the table is grouped. So a group can have multiple pages (Example: Order1 [3pages], Order2 [2pages] ..etc.). So as you said to hide it for an instance of a group won't work and I couldn't find an option like that as well.

Comment: No problem. I would suggest you show your report design and what it looks like at runtime so people have a better understanding. The report design usually influences the answers. Good luck

Comment: Sure I'll try to post it.

Comment: I've posted my design above. If you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the build in functions `=Globals!OverallPageNumber` and `Globals!OverallTotalPages` can only be used in page header and page footer. This might be caused, that the processing of page header and footer are different from the body area.

There is also no workaround.

You cant store the value of `=Globals!OverallPageNumber` in a report variable, you cant reference with `ReportItems!PageNumber.Value` and you cant put the function into the code section.

So what you can do is, copy the tablix from the first page also into the second page and hide the group header on the copied tablix on the second page.

Comment: I couldn't even do that. I have a master tablix which has several sub reports and other sub controls (tablixs, textboxes etc.) in each row. So based on the content there will be 2 or 3 pages and I don't know where the page breaks. So that option won't work for me.